# Change detection running infinitely when function is used with ngIf

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic 2 project. The template has a ngIf to check if its the right user.

`show.ts`

```
  constructor( public book: Bookemon ){}
  rightUser(){
    console.log('right user');
    return this.book.rightUser(this.hunt.user.id);
  }
```

`bookemon.ts` (`bookemon` and `auth` are services )

```
  rightUser(id: number){
    return this.auth.user.id === id;
  }
```

`show.html`

```
<ion-content  fullscreen="true">
  <div id="image-modal" >
    <img [src]="imageSource(hunt.picture_url)" (click)="dismissModal()" >
    <button ion-fab mini *ngIf = " !hunt.picture_url " (click)="showEditHuntModal()" color="ionic">
      <ion-icon  name="add" ></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button color="danger" class="new-claim" ion-button round icon-left *ngIf = "rightUser() && hunt.claims.length " (click)="openClaimModal(hunt)">
      <ion-icon name="trophy"></ion-icon>
      New Claim
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="hunt-content">
    <button small clear ion-button icon-only class="options" *ngIf="rightUser()" (click)="presentAction()">
      <ion-icon name="md-more"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <hunt [hunt]="hunt" [huntedUser]="huntedUser" ></hunt>
  </div>
  <ion-fab *ngIf="hunt.dfu !== undefined" bottom (click)="dismissModal('rejected')"   class="close-fab">
    <button ion-fab   color="danger" ><ion-icon  name="close" ></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-fab>
  <ion-fab *ngIf="hunt.dfu !== undefined" bottom (click)="dismissModal('accepted')"  class="heart-fab">
    <button ion-fab  color="primary"    ><ion-icon  name="heart" ></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

The template displays some content based on `*ngIf = "rightUser()"`

Everything works fine except , the console is logged with **infinitely many** `right user` which comes from `rightUser()` function. The expected behaviour should be `right user` logged once in console and no more change detection being run.

Is it a bad practice to use functions in `ngIf` ? What is triggering change detection infinite times  here?

**Edit**

I tried a function with `ngIf` in a fresh project and it doesnt run change detection infinite times. I am not sure whats causing it here. Here is my `show.ts` in case that helps.

```
export class ShowPage {
  hunt: Hunt ;
  huntedUser: User;
  editHuntPage= EditHuntPage;
  claimHuntPage = ClaimHuntPage;
  rightUser: Boolean;
  constructor(public alert: AlertController , public modal: ModalController, public events: Events
    , public toastCtrl: ToastController, private navParams: NavParams , public action: ActionSheetController
    , public book: Bookemon , public viewCtrl: ViewController, public nav: NavController) {
    console.log(navParams.data);
    this.hunt = navParams.data.hunt;
    this.rightUser = this.book.rightUser(this.hunt.id);
  }
  ionViewDidLoad(){
    console.log('view');
    if(this.hunt.status == "hunted"){
      this .book.getHuntedUser(this.hunt).subscribe( (res) => {
        this.huntedUser = res.json();
        console.log(this.huntedUser);
      })
    }
  }
  imageSource(pic: string){
    return pic ? pic : CONFIG.noHuntPic ;
  }
  dismissModal(status?: string){
    console.log('dismiss');
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(status);
  }
  presentAction(){
    let actionSheet = this.action.create(
    {
      title: this.hunt.title ,
      buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Edit',
        handler: () => {
          let trans = actionSheet.dismiss();
          trans.then( () => {
            this.showEditHuntModal();
          })
          return false;
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Delete',
        role: 'destructive',
        handler: () => {
          let trans = actionSheet.dismiss();
          trans.then( () => {
            this.deleteAlert();
          })
          return false;
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
      }
      ]
    })
    actionSheet.present();
  }
  showEditHuntModal(){
    let modal = this.modal.create(EditHuntPage,this.hunt);
    modal.present();
    modal.onDidDismiss( (data) => {
      if(data){
        this.hunt = data;
      }
    })
  }
  deleteAlert(){
    let alert = this.alert.create({
      title: 'Confirm',
      message: 'Do you want to delete this hunt?',
      buttons: [{
        text: "Delete",
        handler: () => { this.deleteHunt() }
      }, {
        text: "Cancel",
        role: 'cancel'
      }]
    })
    alert.present();
  }
  deleteHunt(){
    this.book.deleteHunt(this.hunt.id).subscribe( (res) => {
      // this.events.publish("user-hunts:deleted",this.hunt);
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss("deleted",this.hunt);
    }, (err) => {
      this.handleError(err);
    })
  }
  openClaimModal(hunt){
    let claimModal =  this.modal.create(ShowClaimPage,{hunt: hunt})
    claimModal.present();
  }
   rightUser(){
     console.log('right user');
     return this.book.rightUser(this.hunt.user.id);
  }
  handleError(err){
    console.log(err);
    let error= err.message ? err.message : "Error occured";
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({ message: error, duration: 2000 , position: 'top'});
    toast.present();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

angular uses zones.js to detect if  something changes in your app so it will check `ngIf` each time, you can this something like this :

```
 <button small clear ion-button icon-only class="options" *ngIf="isRightUser" (click)="presentAction()">
      <ion-icon name="md-more"></ion-icon>
 </button> 
//...
<button small clear ion-button icon-only class="options" *ngIf="isRightUser" (click)="presentAction()">


   //show.ts
   isRightUser:boolean;
   constructor( public book: Bookemon ){}
   ngOnInit(){
     this.isRightUser= rightUser();
   }

   rightUser(){
      return this.book.rightUser(this.hunt.user.id);
   }
```

Comment: So the function should be run only once after loading right?

Comment: @raj yes exactly

Comment: As  I mentioned in my question, it runs infinitely in my case. And thats my issue.

Comment: because there is an other ngIf that calls `rightUser` method, just replace `rightUser()` with `isRightUser` in you template , see the update.

Comment: Can you explain how the other ``ngIf`` would trigger an infinite change detection ?

Comment: as I said when something happens in your app such as a button click, angular must update the app, so it checks the properties of every component and directive (`ngIf` in your case) and verify if their properties has changed or not and since you are using a function `rightUser()` in the `ngIf` directive it must execute it to have the return value;

Comment: don't forget that the property of `ngIf` is itself.

Comment: ``rightUser()`` remains ``false`` after view has been loaded. So why is it being run infinitely ?

Comment: this is because you have something that changes infinitely in your app, something like `setInterval`, or an observable that returns an infinite stream of data.

Comment: see this example you will understand : https://plnkr.co/edit/4SfQZxe5QdbGeHhSVX0A?p=preview

Comment: I dont have anything like ``setInterval`` or something which changes each time.  I have added ``show.ts`` , you can take a look.